# simplify line items in cart Wordpress/ WooCommerce

Tags: arrays, hook-woocommerce

I have just started coding and can't come up with a solution for how the cart adds fees from woo product add-ons extension. The extension currently adds the fees in separate line items at the bottom of the cart, the problem is the add-ons are added for every product I sell and you can end up with 10 or 20 line items for the same add-on. I was trying to condense it down to 4 categories of add-ons and have the categories just iterate the quantity of the category for the cost to add correctly in the cart. I believe the problem comes from checking the ID of the flat rate labels, they are always different when added to the carts I'm not sure how to sort them into each category. I have added this code to my function file in my child theme.
Any advice is appreciated.

This is my first try, shrinks how the flat rate label is displayed but still adds separate line items each time it an add-on is added to the cart.

```
add_filter( 'pewc_flat_rate_label', function( $flat_rate_label, $id, $flat_rate ) {
    static $i = 1;
    $logo_ids = array(349, 649, 1177, 1456, 1460);
    $class_change_ids = array(329, 1181, 1463);
    $place_change_ids = array(348, 1180, 1462);
    $text_id = 1736;
    $setup_ids = array(328, 1175, 1458);

    if ( in_array( explode("_", $id)[1], $logo_ids ) ) {
        return "Logo-" . $i++;
    } elseif ( in_array( explode("_", $id)[1], $class_change_ids ) ) {
        return "Class Changes-" . $i++;
    } elseif ( in_array( explode("_", $id)[1], $place_change_ids ) ) {
        return "Place Changes-" . $i++;
    } elseif ( explode("_", $id)[1] == $text_id ) {
        return "Text";
    } elseif ( in_array( explode("_", $id)[1], $setup_ids ) ) {
        return "Set Up-" . $i++;
    }
    
    return $flat_rate_label;
}, 10, 3 );
```

I have tried this but then the cart only adds the category once and doesn't add any future adds to the cart.I like how this displays to the customer but can't get it to add right.

```
add_filter( 'pewc_flat_rate_label', function( $flat_rate_label, $id, $flat_rate ) {
    static $i = 1;
    $logo_ids = array(349, 649, 1177, 1456, 1460);
    $class_change_ids = array(329, 1181, 1463);
    $place_change_ids = array(348, 1180, 1462);
    $text_id = 1736;
    $setup_ids = array(328, 1175, 1458);

    if ( in_array( explode("_", $id)[1], $logo_ids ) ) {
        return "Logo";
    } elseif ( in_array( explode("_", $id)[1], $class_change_ids ) ) {
        return "Class Changes";
    } elseif ( in_array( explode("_", $id)[1], $place_change_ids ) ) {
        return "Place Changes";
    } elseif ( explode("_", $id)[1] == $text_id ) {
        return "Text";
    } elseif ( in_array( explode("_", $id)[1], $setup_ids ) ) {
        return "Set Up";
    }
    
    return $flat_rate_label;
}, 10, 3 );
```